# deploying a styles library for plugin developers

Tags: wpf, styles

I have an application that my customers can write plugins (that have WPF UIs) for. Now I would like to expose a set of styles as a library that they can use and that will help them with the development of the UIs sO they don't have to reivent the weel. How would I idealy expose those styles without actually having to deploy a lot of xaml files? How is something like this usually done in WPF so it does not break tooling support (blend, vs). How do I expose it and how does the cusomer reference those styles?